# Custom 12bit unsigned integer in matlab with wrap overflow

Tags: matlab

I'm working with code which requires me to have 12 bit unsigned integers in MATLAB which also allow for wrap overflows.

So basically I want to do something like this in matlab:

```
uint12(4095) + uint12(1) // = 0
uint12(0) - uint12(1) // = 4095
```

How would I achieve this?

Note: Practically speaking I just need to integer math, I don't care about space saving. The reason I want it in such a way is because of how all of the code is already structured.

Note 2: Fixed point designer is available.

Comment: Is a license for the fixed point designer available?

Comment: @Daniel Yes it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to initialize your values:

```
nBits = 12; % whatever you want
value = 53; % whatever you want
A = fi(value, 0, nBits, 0, ...
       'OverflowAction', 'Wrap', ...
       'SumMode', 'KeepLSB', ...
       'SumWordLength', nBits);
```

Update: Example of Behavior

```
isSigned = 0; % Value is Unsigned
floatingPoints = 0; % Value is Integer
nBits = 10; % whatever you want
valueA = 1023; % This is Max value = 2^nBins - 1
A = fi(valueA, isSigned, nBits, floatingPoints, ...
       'OverflowAction', 'Wrap', ...
       'SumMode', 'KeepLSB', ...
       'SumWordLength', nBits);
valueB = 0;  % This is Min value
B = fi(valueB, isSigned, nBits, floatingPoints, ...
       'OverflowAction', 'Wrap', ...
       'SumMode', 'KeepLSB', ...
       'SumWordLength', nBits);

%% Testing
R = A + 1 % Displays R = 0    , and all it's properties => 0 is Min Value
R = B - 1 % Displays R = 1023 , and all it's properties => 1023 = 2^nBits - 1 => Max Value
```

Comment: @Ortix92 . I have updated the answer, reply me if you want something else.